# Conditional format in HTML Web app table

Tags: google-apps-script

How to use the color based conditional format in HTML Web app table, 
I have published the sheet table in HTML web-app data consists of SLA and its Status. If SLA Status is violated then color should be highlighted in "Red"

Please refer my sheet for detailed code [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6HK879slQZDuKzdDzng8SnMOce-2u9_IA7E2Luhj5k/edit#gid=1454544052)

```js
function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1k6HK879slQZDuKzdDzng8SnMOce-2u9_IA7E2Luhj5k')
      .getSheetByName("Sheet2")
      .getDataRange()
      .getDisplayValues();
      
}
```

```html
<? var data = getData(); ?> 
<table id="mytable" class="table display table-striped table-bordered responsive-utilities jambo_table">
 

<thead>

        <tr>
            <th>
                Date 
            </th>

            <th>
                BU Unit 
            </th>

            <th >
                Project Name
            </th>

            <th >
                Project Created
            </th>

            <th >
                Chargeback
            </th>

            <th >
                Timeline
            </th>

            <th>SLA Status</th>
        </tr>


        </thead>
    <tbody>

              <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
      
    </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td ></td>
            </tr>

        </tfoot>
        
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add if loop to achieve this.

```
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
        <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { 
          if(j == 6 && data[i][j] == "Timeline Violated"){?>
            <td style='color:red !important;'>
                <?= data[i][j] ?>
            </td>
            <? }else{ ?>
                <td>
                    <?= data[i][j] ?>
                </td>
                <? }} ?>
    </tr>
    <? } ?>
```